# PHP SQL: GROUP BY as array index

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this query for mysql:

```
SELECT HOUR(time),COUNT(*) FROM pageview WHERE time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 HOUR) GROUP BY HOUR(time)
```

For example, this is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [HOUR(time)] => 1
            [COUNT(*)] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [HOUR(time)] => 10
            [COUNT(*)] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [HOUR(time)] => 11
            [COUNT(*)] => 5
        )

)
```

However I want the output like this

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [10] => 4
    [11] => 5
)
```

The array index should be the value of `[HOUR(time)]`.
I would prefer directly by changing the query.

To fetch the data I use this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$views = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: How do you fetch the data? Given an array, you may be able to convert to your desired mode. Just with the MySQL you cannot.

Comment: @fedorqui I added how I fetch data to the question.
@ haseeb this does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indexes in mysql results create automatically , to achieve your goal loop through your first array and create new one as you want

```
$result = array();
foreach($views as $row) {
    $result[$row['HOUR(time)']] =  array( 'COUNT(*)' =>  $row['COUNT(*)']);
}
print_r($result); // check output
```

or simpler form

```
$result = array();
foreach($views as $row) {
    $result[$row['HOUR(time)']] =  $row['COUNT(*)'];
}
print_r($result); // check output
```

Comment: so consider accept answer or vote up :) @user3449482

Comment: Ok, I will. Another question: I want to display the value of the arrays (from 1 to 12) seperated with a comma. How can I make this simpler? Instead of: `echo $result[0].', '.$result[1].', '.$result[2].', '.$result[3].', '.$result[4].', '.$result[5]` ? Can I convert it somehow to a string like that instead of an array?

Comment: use `implode()` like this `echo implode(', ', $result);` look docs on [php.net](http://us1.php.net/implode)

Comment: This skips empty arrays. I want to display the results $result[0] to $result[12] and display a "0" if it's not defined.

Comment: so write `foreach` and check items and if empty print `0`

Comment: to define new array in php write this `$result = array();` this define empty array for you then you can add item to it like this `$result[] ="value";` take a look to [php documentation for arrays](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
$res = array();
foreach($views as $data)
{
 $res[$data['HOUR(time)']] =  array( 'COUNT(*)' =>  $data['COUNT(*)']);
}
print_r($res);
```